# openssl: verify signature but ignore expiration date

Tags: openssl, x509

Is it possible to verify a signature using openssl, but ignore the notAfter expiration date, i.e. have the verification succeed even the notAfter date is in the past?

The use case - simplified a lot - is an embedded controller containing code signed by a third party. When this controller is first powered up, it must check the signature of the code before executing it.

This must also work if the controller is first powered up long after the certificate used for signing the code has expired. (i.e. it is a replacement part pulled from the shelf after a few years)

(The verification of the signature will also use a CRL which will keep revocations even after the certificate expired, so revoked certificates can be detected even then)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes as the code to "verify" the certificate is almost always user code, openssl just provides .

If you take a SSL Socket as an example:

This is not really openssl specific but every implementation of a SSL socket allow you to provide your own function to implement server (or client) certificate verification where the application can decide if the certificate can be trusted or not.

Without you providing a concrete example of what you are trying to do there is not much more of an answer that anyone can give.

Also, certificate revocation is generally considered as [broken](https://scotthelme.co.uk/revocation-is-broken/) and is not normally used.  If you do use it you may run into [performance](https://news.netcraft.com/archives/2013/04/16/certificate-revocation-and-the-performance-of-ocsp.html) issues.